# Applying style to random grid space

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a simple numeracy game where by there is a grid populated with numbers. The numbers are hidden and when the game is run the grid space is highlighted. A div on the side produces a sum to help the user get the correct answer. The user then clicks the corresponding numbers that animate into position and signal whether they are right or wrong.

The problem I am having is that when the program is run a trigger('click') function should select an area at random in the grid and apply the class `.spellword`. This will highlight the area purple, indicating where to place an answer.

At the moment when I run the program nothing happens and I do not know why. I have made the same game but with words and it worked fine.

Here is the function for the button

```
$('.minibutton').click(function() {

$('.minibutton').prop('disabled', false);
$('.picstyle').show();
$('td').removeClass('spellword');
var r = rndWord;
while (r == rndWord) {
    rndWord = Math.floor(Math.random() * (listOfWords.length));
}

$('td[data-word="' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + '"]').addClass('spellword');
$('td[data-word=' + word + ']').removeClass('wordglow').removeClass('wordglow4').removeClass('wordglow3').css('color', 'transparent');

var noExist = $('td[data-word=' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + ']').hasClass('wordglow2');
if (noExist) {
    $('.minibutton').click();

} else {

  $('.picstyle').text(sum);

}

}).trigger("click");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZAfVZ/33/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data-letter and data-word are blank on every table cell. That's why your code is failing.

**Edit:** see [this JSFiddle for a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZAfVZ/36/). When assigning data-letter to your table cell you were missing a string cast (`word.toString()[k]`). You still have a handful of table cells with no answer and no `data-word` - is this intentional?

Comment: I don't see how though all I have done is change a working word game to a number game by changing the letters for numbers. @MassivePenguin

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/7Y7A5/2/ - This is the word game. All I want to do is change the picture to a sum and the letters to numbers. Why is it not working? @MassivePenguin

Comment: Best guess would be that your code is having issues treating the sums (and answers) as numbers, rather than strings. Try explicitly casting every sum/answer as a string BEFORE performing any logic on it. If you don't need to perform mathematical functions on the sum text that this may solve your issue.

Comment: No I don't need anything mathematical, I literally want to match strings to strings. How would I cast them as strings? @MassivePenguin

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Comment: would I have to write var 1 = new Object();
1.toString();  var 2 = new Object();
2.toString(); for all my numbers or is there a way to do it for all? @MassivePenguin

Comment: No, before you do any logic on a value (e.g. `if (word.length <= spaceAvail) { foundIndex = index; return true; })`, convert it to a string: `if (word.toString().length <= spaceAvail) { foundIndex = index; return true; }`

Comment: Ok so I have done that and it works, but it will not accept right answers now. Ant idea why? @MassivePenguin

Comment: How are you determining if an answer is correct? Can you share an updated Fiddle?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18280/discussion-between-massivepenguin-and-milo-j)